# Unicode sequence for custom character with dot underneath

Tags: unicode, diacritics

Unicode has code points for certain Roman characters with a dot underneath, for instance `U+1E04` — "Latin Capital Letter B With Dot Below" but code points don't exist for all letters.

How can I put a dot below an arbitrary (Roman) character?

I know about code point `U+0323` — the combining dot below diacritical:

- https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0323

But here is how the sequence `\u0323X\u0323C` is rendered: **'̣X̣C'**

I'd like to get a dot under the C as well as the X. In some renderings I see two dots under the X and in others I see only one dot under the X. In either case there is no dot under the C.

Comment: Can you see this correctly? **X̣C̣** idk how you're entering your data, but strictly you add the combining character *after* the one you want to combine with, otherwise you'd get  ̣X̣C, or as in your example above, under the first quote '̣X̣C'

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that for me!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you're entering your data backwards. The combining character *follows* the letter it's to combine with, rather than leading it.

That way you get **X̣C̣** rather than  ̣X̣C, or as in your example above, under the first quote '̣X̣C'